# JavaScript file manager with column view

Tags: javascript

I would like to share documents on my homepage in column-view, so it feels like browsing in Marlin or Finder. How would I start out to do this with JavaScript? Possibly any JS libraries?
I do not have access to any serverside coding, though the server supports PHP5.

[image: Malin file manager]

Comment: Where are the documents that you want to share stored?  If they're on a server you'll either need to maintain the URL's to each document manually or use server-side scripting to automate the process.  If the documents are on your desktop/laptop things will get trickier (For one thing, you'd need to run a webserver on the desktop/laptop which may be in violation of your school's acceptable use policies)

Comment: The documents are on the schools server, buti can access them from anywhere with VPN.

Comment: Were you able to use jqWidgets or one of the other libraries to build your file explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UI library. Alternatives with similar UI controls are [Sencha](http://sencha.com), [jQWidgets](http://jqwidgets.com), [KendoUI](http://kendoui.com), [Wijmo](http://wijmo.com).

For example you can use the jqxMenu by jQWidgets.

The file browsing can be done using the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader) but probably you'll need already defined list of files (the use of the File API will be for extra file information).

Comment: Thanks! Have you seen any specific examples? For instance the treeview (http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/index.html) looks really good, but not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't have an experience with Kendo but here is an example with jqxTree http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/defaultfunctionality.htm?classic

Answer (score 0):

the guys at sencha make a cracking library which could mimick the Finder style/look, have a look at some of their examples at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example but would require some serverside coding to return the file data you wish to display...

Comment: Unfortunately my page is on my school's server, so i can't do any serverside coding :(